# Build section is not showing while setting jenkins configuration

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POZfa.png)Build section is not showing while setting jenkins configuration in  manage_jenkins>configure_system where we set POM root path and goals in latest version of jenkins i.e 2.7 while this option is available in previous versions.

Comment: in Jenkins 2.x versions

Comment: you need to provide more detail on your question

Comment: Provide more details like what kind of job have you created?

Answer (score 3):

Choose "Maven project" while creating a Jenkins Job that gives the Build options. Freestyle projects may not show the option.

Answer (score 1):

'PRE Steps' option is not showing in jenkins latest version i.e 2.7

[click here to see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LShpJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **Maven Integration plugin** first and then create a **Maven Project** when you click on **New Item**. Now you will be able to see the **PRE STEPS** options.

Answer (score 0):

if it's maven project you can add steps only with pre-steps and post-steps[image]

Comment: 'PRE Steps' option is not showing in jenkins latest version i.e 2.7

Comment: PLS verify you have all required mvn plugins.